# PySpark not importing local module when launched from Oozie

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, oozie

I've a PySpark job that runs flawlessly when launched using `spark-submit`, but I keep getting errors when trying to launch it using an Oozie Spark Action. This is the structure of the `lib` directory in my workspace.

```
lib/
    main_spark.py
    localmodule/
        ClassOne.py
```

What I'm getting is this error:

```
>> from localmodule.ClassOne import ClassOne
ImportError: No module named localmodule.ClassOne
```

It looks like my main py file cannot solve the reference to localmodule, even if they're both in the lib directory and should therefore copied in the same directory.
Am I missing something?

Comment: I never used the Spark action specifically, but usually Oozie is *very* verbose about the HDFS resources that have been downloaded into the YARN "launcher" container. Did you inspect the YARN logs, especially the top of *stdout* for container #2 (i.e. the "launcher", since #1 has to be the YARN AppMaster)?

Comment: In your workflow.xml, did you specify argument `py-files` with full path to localmodule?.

Comment: @Pushkr no, py-files should only accept a .egg file, not a path.